# bower_components not loading with express static

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, bower

I'm making an express app using bower, but somehow the bower_components folder isn't found. I've searched here, tried all solutions, but nothing worked.

In my server.js I have:

/server/app.js

```
// Set static files
app.use(express.static('app'));
app.use('/bower_components', express.static(__dirname + '/bower_components'));
```

In the index

/app/index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" /></script>
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>   
...
```

And what I get:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css 
(index):85 GET http://localhost:3000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js 
(index):86 GET http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js 

Cannot GET /bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css
...
```

It works if I remove the "/bower_components" prefix from the tags, and change in server to this:

```
server.js
app.use(express.static('bower_components'));

index.html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
```

Comment: Is your bower_components folder inside your server folder? Otherwise the code is wrong.

Comment: No, my bower_components is in the root.

Comment: Then try the modifications proposed below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be caused by bower_components folder outside your server folder. Modify your code at `server/app.js` to this:

```
var path = require('path');

app.use('/bower_components', express.static(path.dirname(__dirname) + '/bower_components'));
```

Here i'm using the `dirname()` funtion from the `path` built in nodejs package to get the parent folder of your server folder.

Comment: Thanks!! Works perfectely.  I've tried the "path.join", but not this one.

Comment: If this solve your issue please mark it as the correct answer